# Encoding string function for apostrophe objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, character-encoding, nsstring

http://php.weenggs.com/scrap/service.php?op=search&search_term=Crabbie's ->my api 
http://php.weenggs.com/scrap/service.php?op=search&search_term=Crabbie%20 ->want like this

```
[myStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

is convert blank space to %20 same way I want to convert 's to %20.

Comment: There is no question, so what do you want to know?

Comment: %20 means a space character in escaped URI

Comment: @BuntyMadan : You are right

Comment: @user2239835 so that was your Question ?

Comment: One function is in my qustion which is convert blank space to %20 same way i want to convert apostrophe to %20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this you can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` method,

here it replaces occurence of `'s` with `%20`

```
    str=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'s" withString: @"%20"];


NSString *str=@"http://php.weenggs.com/scrap/service.php?op=search&search_term=Crabbie's";
    str=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'s" withString: @"%20"];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

O/P:-

http://php.weenggs.com/scrap/service.php?op=search&search_term=Crabbie%20

Comment: @user2239835:have you checked this one?

Comment: How can i convert Crabbie's to Crabbie%20?

Comment: take that url in string and convert it using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString method ,once check my answer i have clearly explained it.

Comment: [Crabbie's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'s" withString: @"%20"]; then it'l returns like Crabbie%20 .